# Word for "helping work"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

> **Speaker A:** You got a new babysitting job?
>
> **Speaker B:** No, it's just a [...]. No payment.

Speaker B is just going to do a "helping work", say, taking care of a friend's cat while the friend is on vacation.

Is there a word or phrase for these type of "works"?

Comment: Probably - odd job (considering that there is no or less motivation/willingness to perform job)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing someone a **favor** is also used in this context.

> **Favor**[[1]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/favor)[[2]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/do-someone-a-favor?q=do+someone+a+favor)
>
> 1: a kind or helpful act that you do for someone
>
> 2: do something for someone as an act of kindness

*... No, it's just a **favor**. No payment.*

Comment: IMO, favor is the best choice here. +1. And a little edit, if that's okay.

Answer (score 4):

A **volunteer** is someone who chooses to do something for no payment.

From [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volunteer) online:

> volunteer
>
> 1: a person who chooses to join the military
>
> 2: a person who does work without getting paid to do it

So you could say it is a *volunteer position.*

Answer (score 1):

*Reciprocation can also fit in depending on the context.*

> Speaker B: No, it's just a [**[reciprocation](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reciprocation)**]. No payment.

- (n) [*the act of making or doing something in return*](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reciprocation)
- [*a return in kind or of like value*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocation)

(Vocabulary.com/M-W)

> Type of: getting even, paying back, return.